# How to Transpose rows to columns in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the sample data as below

```
emp_id   period    name    flg   Commissions
1       201601     dummy   y     2396739.53
1       201602     dummy   y     3291814.83
1       201603     dummy   y     1418367.9
1       201604     dummy   y     2884582.31
2       201601     mummy   y     3396739.53
2       201602     mummy   y     3291814.83
2       201603     mummy   y     1428367.9
2       201604     mummy   y     7884582.31
```

I need to transpose the data as below.

```
emp_id   name   flg  201601:commission  201602:commission  201603:commission  201604:commission    ------
1        dummy   y    2396739.53       3291814.83         1418367.9        2884582.31
2        mummy   y    3396739.53       3291814.83         14218367.9       7884582.31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number of columns you can use conditional aggregation, as in:

```
select
  emp_id,
  name,
  flg,
  sum(case when period = 201601 then commissions end) as 201601_comm,
  sum(case when period = 201602 then commissions end) as 201602_comm,
  sum(case when period = 201603 then commissions end) as 201603_comm,
  sum(case when period = 201604 then commissions end) as 201604_comm,
  ...
from t
group by emp_id, name, flg
order by emp_id, name, flg
```

If you don't know the number of columns, then you can't do it in SQL. Essentially you want a "pivot" operation.

Comment: Thank you. I have period for 4 years (i.e) 12X4 is there a easy dynamic way to do this?

Comment: Dynamic SQL falls outside the domain of SQL, and it's up to the language you are using. You can do it by simpluy concatenating strings. Also, pretty much all ORMs out there have some kind of dynamic SQL features you can explore.